# Default value in textbox with Angular

Tags: angularjs, html

Let's say i have a field called phone Number , i want to add a default value to the the textbox like :
[image]
and i dont wanna let user to delete or change it with firebug or something .
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but I think you want this

```
<input type="text" value="ja" name="lname" readonly>
```

User can't change the value of the input type, the intup type is prefilled with "ja" as that is the value

in your case:

```
<input type="text" value="91" name="phone_number" readonly>
```

Comment: If you make it disable, user will not be able to enter any input.. Than what is the need of textbox here...

Comment: Oh you want it that way, How I've done it with my phone number code is that I used 2 form input types. 1 with already filled +31 ( as I live in the netherlands ^^)  and the  second one was open for users to fill the rest of their number. works good.

Comment: this should be the answer he is looking for, if it does not work let me know;)

Comment: it's got to be a better way guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716784/can-a-text-box-be-half-read-only-and-half-editable   is this maybe what you looking for?